# (Browser-as-Client) HTTP 405 on $.ajax POST to a Node service

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, http-status-code-405, http-status-code-406

**BACKGROUND**

First things first, I have a Restify service running on Node which is working perfectly when I use a GUI HTTP client. I only state the previous to highlight, that this is a browser-centric issue. And if a server-side solution is needed, it is to accomodate the browser...

Here are the 100% functional HTTP requests and responses using my Restify web service and a GUI HTTP client:

**Request** -

```
POST /appointments HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:8085
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.1.1 (Macintosh; OS X/10.10.1) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 142

{
  "eventName": "Fiesta Forever",
  "time": "Fri Dec 19 2014 15:55:00 GMT-0600 (CST)",
  "phoneNumber": "13125555555"
}
```

**Response**-

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 37
Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 23:01:29 GMT
Connection: close

{"message":"Alright Alright Alright"}
```

And more importantly, my server creates a future cron job, which can be seen in my server's console:

```
Created: Fri Dec 19 2014 14:55:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

---

---

**THE PROBLEM**

My problem is that I am trying to write a browser interface to my service. And I am getting an error when I try making the same HTTP request using Ajax. I created the following test function which makes the HTTP request:

```
function testPost() {
    var jsonBody = "{\"eventName\": \"Fiesta Forever\",\"time\": \"Fri Dec 19 2014 14:15:00 GMT-0600 (CST)\",\"phoneNumber\": \"13125555555\"}";

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8085/appointments',
        accepts: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonBody,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":true
           }
    });

}
```

I then load my page containing that function in my iOS emulator, and call the function from the Safari Developer console. I receive the following error:

[image]

EDIT: Upon removing the request headers, I receive: 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)`

**SERVER-CODE**

Here is the code on my server. I took the following code from the Express docs, because they were the only solution which actually seemed to add the correct headers to every response:

```
//CORS
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000");
    next();
});
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to make a cross domain HTTP request using $.ajax which carries and receives JSON?

Comment: Is the server.use above all the other http request callbacks? if not move it above it

Comment: The 405 is a bit weird. The cross-origin error is not, that stuff is difficult and has many quirks. For the 405, I would do a `console.log()` on the headers and method in the `req` object of your Node service just to be sure you know what the server is trying to handle.

Comment: Ryan, thank you for your tip, but moving the server.use above all others did not solve the problem. Jakerella, I would love to inspect the incoming `req`s in the node service, but I can't seem to find a breakpoint which is hit. The request doesn't actually hit my `/appointments/` endpoint, so I can't put a breakpoint there or within the function handler.

Comment: _Sending_ an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with your _request_ is nonsense – that header has to be send in _response_ by the server – so remove it from your AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that could very well be the case.

Comment: CBroe, making that change braught me to a 406 error, Progress!?

Comment: 406 means (by definition), that the server is not capable of serving a response of the type you requested via `Accept` header. Try removing `accepts: 'application/json'` from your AJAX settings – does that change anything?

Comment: CBroe, you solved it. Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, I’ll sum that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a *response* header that has to be send by the server – sending it as a *request* header with the client request does not only not make sense, but seems to be what makes the server refuse your request here – because with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept` it told you what request headers it will accept, and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not among those.

After that you got a `406 Not Acceptable`, meaning the server did not see itself able to respond with data of a content type that was requested via the `Accept` header. So removing `accepts: 'application/json'` does make jQuery not tell the server any more that you expect a specific content type, but just “give me whatever you got” – which in this case seems to satisfy the server …

… and make it respond with `Content-Type: application/json` anyway, which is kinda weird, because that should be exactly what jQuery was asking for (and your first request via GUI showed as well). I don’t know if jQuery makes something else out of that setting (you could try and see if your browser’s developer tools network panel shows anything wrong with the request headers) … but problem solved, and that’s what counts, right? :-)